# Apache2 droplet CPU usage 100% starting the server

Tags: php, apache, nginx, digital-ocean

Our system went down this morning, and from that point on we had some problems on the website.

Right now the Magento 2 installation that we run for months now is fine again, but it is insanely slow. I could not figure out where it was coming from before I ran on my command line `htop`

Which displays the following:

[image: htop log]

I checked the error log and got the following out of it, but I am not sure if that is relevant to the issue:

```
[Wed May 02 07:21:21.415818 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3208] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed May 02 07:21:22.157176 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3533] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Wed May 02 07:21:22.196862 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3534] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Wed May 02 07:21:22.199047 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3534] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed May 02 07:21:22.199075 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3534] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Wed May 02 07:55:41.494929 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3534] AH00051: child pid 4344 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
    [Wed May 02 07:55:44.498261 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3534] AH00045: child process 4488 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
    [Wed May 02 07:55:46.500484 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3534] AH00045: child process 4488 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
    [Wed May 02 07:55:48.502752 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3534] AH00045: child process 4488 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
    [Wed May 02 07:55:50.504919 2018] [core:error] [pid 3534] AH00046: child process 4488 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
    [Wed May 02 07:55:51.506194 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3534] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed May 02 07:55:52.227437 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4620] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Wed May 02 07:55:52.269253 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4621] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Wed May 02 07:55:52.271855 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4621] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed May 02 07:55:52.271879 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4621] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.151659 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4621] AH00051: child pid 5142 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.151741 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4621] AH00051: child pid 5145 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.151783 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4621] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.900700 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5234] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.939956 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5235] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.942188 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5235] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed May 02 08:14:20.942210 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5235] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407132 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3388 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407193 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3389 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407202 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3324 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407228 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3355 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407234 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3448 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407239 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3406 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:14.407246 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3455 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409420 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3388 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409472 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3389 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409484 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3324 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409504 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3355 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409509 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3448 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409518 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3406 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:16.409524 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3455 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.411663 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3388 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.412247 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3389 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.412256 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3324 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.412261 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3355 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.412267 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3448 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.412272 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3406 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:18.412277 2018] [core:warn] [pid 3208] AH00045: child process 3455 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414410 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3388 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414498 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3389 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414516 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3324 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414524 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3355 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414535 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3448 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414548 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3406 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed May 02 07:21:20.414556 2018] [core:error] [pid 3208] AH00046: child process 3455 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
```

Am I looking in the correct direction? I checked the following settings as well:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers              3
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers           10
        MaxRequestWorkers         150
        MaxConnectionsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I changed this and did some restart for apache, but cant figure out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, as you can see from the [help]. Your question *may* suit other sites, like Server Fault, but do read their help section first and do a search before posting to see if it fits there and if there already is something relating to this issue.

Comment: I checked but I cannot find the error there nor post.